# Postgres get rows having at least 1 specific value in column group by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql command:

```
select location,status,total from my_table
```

This return:

```
location - status - total
city a - active - 3
city a - pending - 2
city a - cancel - 4
city b - pending - 4
city b - cancel - 4
city c - active - 2
city c - cancel - 6
```

How can i return only the rows with cities where having at least once the status active and total >= 1?

So, i want to return:

```
    location - status - total
    city a - active - 3
    city a - pending - 2
    city a - cancel - 4
    city c - active - 2
    city c - cancel - 6
```

As you notice i dont want to return the city b cause it hasn't the status active at least one time with total >= 1.

Comment: `where location in (select location from my_table where ...)`

Comment: WHERE EXISTS with a subquery can handle that, or IN

Comment: Your question answers half of it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how can i make that query with exists function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select location,status,total from my_table
where location in (
    select location from my_table
    where status = 'active'
        and total >= 1
    )
```

Comment: that query ignores the rest rows and return only the rows with an active status..i want to return the cities where having at least once the status active but i want to return all of them..ex: city a - active - 3, city a - pending - 2, city a - cancel - 4. The city b has no status active so i don't want that location..so, i dont need any rows with city b.. but for city a i need 3 rows instead of 1..

Comment: This query would do exactly what you need, just go ahead and try it.

it is a subquery in a query. The inner (sub) query will find the cities where have at least one line with both active and total-1. In your case this will be cities A and C. it will then pass them to the parent query and will filter all the rows with city A and C, including those where the status is not active/ total-1.